# Multiple query in node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

Got some trouble with my multiple sql query in nodejs, using mysql module. Even if the user exist, it will create a new user, so there is probably a problem in this :

```
if (rows[0].exist == "0") { // if not exist, create it (already authentified by wordpress)
```

I've already tried without the quote, but same problem, won't update, just insert.

```
 function _databaseProcess() {
        var existUser = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as exist FROM user WHERE display_name = "?"';
        var insertUser = 'INSERT INTO user SET ?';
        var getUid = 'select uid from user where display_name = "?"';

        pool.getConnection(function(err, db) { // Ask for a connection
            if (err) {
                db.release();
                console.log("Erreur lors de la connexion à la base");
                return;
            }

            console.log('Connexion à la base : id ' + db.threadId);

            db.query(existUser, [data.username], function(err, rows) { // check if user exist
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("resultat : " + rows[0].exist);
                if (rows[0].exist == "0") { // if not exist, create it (already authentified by wordpress)
                    console.log('Première connexion de ' + data.username);
                    uid = uuid.v4();
                    var value = {
                        "display_name": data.username,
                        "uid": uid
                    };
                    db.query(insertUser, value, function(err, rows) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        db.release();
                        console.log("Ajout de l'user " + rows.insertId);

                        _initiateConnection();
                    });
                } else { //else, retrieve the uid
                    db.query(getUid, value, function(err, rows) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        db.release();
                        console.log("UID de l'user : " + rows[0].uid);
                        uid = rows[0].uid;

                        _initiateConnection();
                    });
                }
            });

            db.on('error', function(err) {
                console.log("Erreur dans la base de donnée");
                return;
            });
        });
```

## EDIT

In fact, here is the console output i got :

```
[/#DIM4Opuve1Ov96igAAAB]Requete obtenu, qui est-ce ?
Connexion à la base : id 36525
[ RowDataPacket { exist: 0 } ]
Première connexion de polette
Ajout de l'user 1
[/#DIM4Opuve1Ov96igAAAB] USER: polette => bcf8ebb5-04fc-45d4-8d15-5ee7ae6ec368
polette from socket /#DIM4Opuve1Ov96igAAAB joined the app
Utilisateurs connectés (1) : 
bcf8ebb5-04fc-45d4-8d15-5ee7ae6ec368 (polette) sur le socket /#DIM4Opuve1Ov96igAAAB
polette disconnected
[/#1DIhz2yFipo9VtuzAAAC]Requete obtenu, qui est-ce ?
Connexion à la base : id 36525
[ RowDataPacket { exist: 0 } ]
Première connexion de polette
Ajout de l'user 2
[/#1DIhz2yFipo9VtuzAAAC] USER: polette => d6a73fc1-a650-4b03-89d5-cb96b070e876
polette from socket /#1DIhz2yFipo9VtuzAAAC joined the app
Utilisateurs connectés (1) : 
d6a73fc1-a650-4b03-89d5-cb96b070e876 (polette) sur le socket /#1DIhz2yFipo9VtuzAAAC
```

There is some output you may not understand because i've omitted the code, but the fact we see is, even if polette is in the database, he will not search for his UID, and will create a new one, and in my database, i'll get this (this output is xml exported):

```
<pma_xml_export version="1.0" xmlns:pma="http://www.phpmyadmin.net/some_doc_url/">
    <!--
    - Structure schemas
    -->
    <pma:structure_schemas>
        <pma:database name="node" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
            <pma:table name="user">
                CREATE TABLE `user` (
                  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                  `uid` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
            </pma:table>
        </pma:database>
    </pma:structure_schemas>

    <!--
    - Base de données: 'node'
    -->
    <database name="node">
        <!-- Table user -->
        <table name="user">
            <column name="id">1</column>
            <column name="display_name">polette</column>
            <column name="uid">bcf8ebb5-04fc-45d4-8d15-5ee7ae6ec368</column>
        </table>
        <table name="user">
            <column name="id">2</column>
            <column name="display_name">polette</column>
            <column name="uid">d6a73fc1-a650-4b03-89d5-cb96b070e876</column>
        </table>
    </database>
</pma_xml_export>
```

Comment: You should learn promises and [promisify](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) your db accesses, this code which does almost nothing already is a callback hell

Comment: Yep, next step, but as a beginner in nodejs, i want to understand how to fix my database query like i've made

Comment: Can you try simply `console.log(rows)` instead of `console.log("resultat : " + rows[0].exist);`

Comment: yes, got this, with a user who already exist : [ RowDataPacket { exist: 0 } ]

Comment: Well, then there's something wrong with your query. Does `data.username` have the value you expect?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Molda yes, data.username is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems nodejs prepared a request but even if it's on my database, it send me a empty output.

So i've opened a new question right there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623217/mysql-node-prepared-function